# MySQL first condition match priority

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I have this data

```
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | fromid |            message              |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 |  1213  | this is just an example         |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
|  2 |  1992  | other random message            |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
|  3 |  1364  | example number three            |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+
```

I need to search data where `fromid='1992'` or `message LIKE '%example%'`

if there is any result where `fromid` matches `1992` value, return this result, and ignore second condition

but if there is no result from first condition (`fromid='1992'`), return the result from second condition

can I do that on single query?

Comment: Not really. Just get with `fromid='1992'` and, if no results were found, run a second query for the `like`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using a marker, and then limiting the results to the first row. An example using UNION:-

```
SELECT 1 AS match_type, my_table.* 
from  my_table  
where fromid = 1992 
UNION
SELECT 2 AS match_type, my_table.*
from  my_table  
WHERE message like  '%example%'
ORDER BY match_type
LIMIT 1
```

Down side of this is that it still forces a relatively slow non indexed query using LIKE with a leading wildcard.

The following is an alternative. In most circumstance it would be pointless, but should the check on id be expected to bring back a record almost always, and the check on the LIKE just a very occasional condition (with only a single record ever returned) then it might be worthwhile as it would avoid having the do the slow LIKE condition searched unless necessary.

```
SELECT COALESCE(id, SELECT MAX(id) from my_table WHERE message like '%example%') AS id,
    COALESCE(fromid, SELECT MAX(formed) from my_table WHERE message like '%example%') AS formed,
    COALESCE(message, SELECT MAX(message) from my_table WHERE message like '%example%') AS message 
FROM
(
    SELECT id, fromid, message 
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS a_cnt) sub0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, fromid, message 
        from  my_table  
        where fromid = 1992 
    ) sub1
) sub2
```

Comment: Not speaking about a slow quicksort algorithm (Using filesort) on the match_type column because no index can be used,..